# simple regex in java split

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string `blah-*-bleh-*-bloh`
and I want to split it by `-*-` so I tried (amongst other things):

```
res.split("/-\\*-/g");
```

But it's not working. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java, there is no need for `/` before and `/g` after:

```
String[] splittedArray = res.split("-\\*-");
```